# com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite not mocked Here maps api 4.5

Tags: java, android, here-api

**com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite not mocked** , runtime exception thrown on every time mapViewLite is used (Here maps api 4.5).
(I am not using any automated testing tools, and it happens **only on latest versions of android** ).
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming from the `heresdk-mock` JAR file that enables mocking of all HERE SDK classes. Do not use this in a production version of your app. There's a "UnitTesting" example app on GitHub for Explore / Navigate edition, but the example should also work for Lite with a few adaptions.

Comment: can i have more light on this, like documentation to manage production/debug builds , how to remedy the errors etc..

Comment: I am pasting a link to the Lite documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-lite/4.6.0.0/dev_guide/topics/key-concepts.html#unit-tests ... there is also an example app, but it is available only for another edition, but it should apply to Lite as well: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/android/UnitTesting